# Definition in Operator Theory

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition

I have started learning some *Operator Theory*. I encountered the following definition. I would like to know why it is that the $f(z)$ in the integrand and the $f(a)$ are both labelled as $f$ where it is clear that they are different mappings. I know that this definition is analogous to the *[Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)* but in that case the functions are actually the same. I don't see why this ambiguous notation is a convention. Please advise what the connection is here.

**Riesz-Dunford Functional Analysis**:

Let $a \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital Banach algebra, fix open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sigma(a) \subset U$. Take analytic function $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$.

Choose a system $\Gamma \subset U$ of closed contours such that 
$Ind_{\Gamma}(\lambda) = 1$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(a)$ and $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}:~\text{Ind}_{\Gamma}(z) \neq 0 \} \subset U$.

Define $$f(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma}f(z)(z-a)^{-1}dz$$

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Part of the reason why the notation persists is that $(fg)(a)=f(a)g(a)$ and $1(a)=I$ is the unit.

Comment: @TrialAndError I'm not quite following your reasoning here. I understand that $(fg)(a) = f(a)g(a)$.  By $1(a)$ do you mean $1(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma}(z-a)^{-1}dz$? What is $I$ and what is the connection with the notation?

Comment: The rules of multiplying functions of $a$ and the rules of multiplying functions are the same. The notation is the same. So why distinguish?

Comment: @TrialAndError Oh okay so you are saying that the idea is to look at it in terms of '[functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus)'? Could you please elaborate on what is meant by $1(a) = I$?

Comment: If $f(z) \equiv 1$, then $f(a)=I$ is the identity operator. That's a critical part of the functional calculus: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}(z I-a)^{-1}dz = I$. Then $f(z)=z^{n}$ gives $f(a)=a^{n}$ for $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "functional calculus".  The point is that the function $f$, initially defined on complex numbers, can now be extended to suitable members of the Banach algebra.  Moreover, this extension will turn 
out to have some useful properties.

For a concrete example, consider the Banach algebra $\mathcal L(\mathbb C^n)$ of linear operators on $\mathbb C^n$ (with whatever norm you wish), 
i.e. $n \times n$ matrices, and the analytic function $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ defined on 
$\mathbb C \backslash (-\infty, 0]$.  This definition gives you a way to 
define the square root function on all matrices with no eigenvalues in $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: I just started this topic hence I'm not quite following your concrete example. But how is this an extension? It seems like a completely different function to me. Can you retrieve the complex function $f$ by restricting to members $y \cdot 1$ where $y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $1$ is the unit of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: I hope it's fine that I corrected a typo. Is it? Ah and (+1) of course. :)

Comment: Kind of extension like give reason for a function initially acting on numbers to act on operators now. The point is that functions already form a Banach algebra and this way you obtain a calculus for operators intead also a Banach algebra that is conform with what we started with, e.g. the square of $f(x):=x$ was $g(x):=x^2$ now becomes $f(A):=A$ will be $g(A):=A^2$ or the inverse of $f(x):=x$ was $g(x):=1/x$ now becomes $f(A):=A$ and $g(A):=A^{-1}$. That is quite (I mean really quite) neat! :)

Comment: Imagine you want to know the inverse of $A^2+7A-1$ ;)

Comment: Yes, one of the useful properties is that for $y \in U$, $f(y 1) = f(y) 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You see even in that small statement you wrote it seems unessary to have $f(y1) = f(y)1$ where the $f$s are not the same mapping. You mentioned that it is 'functional calculus' but this is just a defining a new function on a Banach algebra, where is the 'calculus'?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus : In mathematics, a functional calculus is a theory allowing one to apply mathematical functions to mathematical operators. ... The idea of a functional calculus is to create a **principled** approach to this kind of overloading of the notation.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Okay thanks. So in my question $f$ would be the mathematical function and $a$ would be the mathematical operator (since many Banach algebras are operator spaces)?